# Full stack trace missing when using Unity as AOP framework

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, aop

I noticed that when using Unity as AoP framework, particularly VirtualMethodInterceptor + CallHandler.

The stack trace I got does not include the original code. Instead it has a xxx_wrapper_yyyy type of class, which I assume is a class that dynamically inherit from the original class. Understandably since no source code was ever written for the dynamic class, it is not reporting the line number where the error occurred in the original code.

How can I change this? I need the stack trace and line number where the exception was thrown.

FYI the call handler is working as intended otherwise. It's just the exception is missing the line number of the original virtual method where it happened. And no the call handler does not contain any line that will swallow or handle the exception.

Comment: Try coming up with a better (SOLID) design that saves you from using interception :-)

Comment: Dunno I believe AOP complements SOLID not contradicts it.

Comment: If you need Interception, you are missing a abstraction in your system. IMO, you should be able to decorate a set of related classes with a single generic decorator. When doing this, you won't need interception. Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for instance.

Comment: Used it before. Decorator pattern. Has its merits, just not everywhere. Also better on a "green field" project. AoP is more powerful and is a valid solution in many instances. In my case is actually the preferred solution - less code, less changes, less rewrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Wrap_Exception_ThrownByTarget()
{
  var container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<Target>(
    new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(), 
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());
  container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
  var config = container.Configure<Interception>();
  config.AddPolicy("1").AddCallHandler<ExceptionHandler>().AddMatchingRule<AlwaysMatches>();
  var target = container.Resolve<Target>();
  target.AlwaysThrows("foo");
}
public class AlwaysMatches : IMatchingRule
{
  public bool Matches(MethodBase member)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
public class ExceptionHandler : ICallHandler
{
  public int Order { get; set; }
  public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
  {
    IMethodReturn r = getNext()(input, getNext);
    if (r.Exception != null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("CallHandler", r.Exception);
    }
    return r;
  }
}
public class Target
{
  public virtual string AlwaysThrows(string foo)
  {
    throw new Exception("Boom!");
  }
}
```

I get a stacktrace that looks like this

```
   at UnityExceptionAspect.Target.AlwaysThrows(String foo) in C:\VisualStudio\Evaluation\UnityExceptionAspect\Target.cs:line 9
   at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_Target_c49f840ef38c41d7b4d5956223e95f73.<AlwaysThrows_DelegateImplementation>__0(IMethodInvocation inputs, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
```

Sorry for the poor formatting...

It definitely contains the original source of the exception although it is obfuscated by the cryptical information about the generated type.

Comment: Sebastian, this is awesome, I'm gonna try it out, but looks like this is the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing an exception in your call handler. Instead, if you let the method return as normal, your regular exception should simply be exposed. I've only seen getting obfuscated exceptions in the past when the call handler / behaviour itself has blown up.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Exception of the return value to a new exception. For example:

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
{
    IMethodReturn r = getNext()(input, getNext);
    if (r.Exception != null) r.Exception = new Exception("NameOfInterceptor", r.Exception);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Generally yes, that is true. In this case the reason there is no stack trace is because the Unity pipeline doesn't carry the original exception up the pipeline - so your concern is a problem here regardless. I've not had a problem with this approach since the only times I've used AOP was within a pipeline I managed (no other frameworks relied on it). If you needed to tie this in with other frameworks, you'd probably want to construct the new exception using reflection base on the one thrown.

Comment: You missed the point which is that in this scenario Unity's AOP changes 
 the exception to a generic one. So the creation of a new exception and returning that is necessary to get any detail of the exception raised up the stack. Whether that new exception is a different type or the same is up to your needs and use. Which to reiterate: "the Unity pipeline doesn't carry the original exception up the pipeline - so your concern is a problem here regardless"